# Как получить объекты одной модели, на которые нет ссылок из другой модели?

Tags: python, django

Есть модель Art. Есть модель Good у которой есть ForeinKey на Art.
Я хочу в одном запросе получить все объекты Art, на которые не указывают ни один Good.
То есть все art у которых art.good_set.all() - пустой кверисет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

Art.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(Good.objects.filter(art=OuterRef('pk')))
)
```

Документация по [Exists](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries) и [фильтрации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#filtering-on-a-subquery-or-exists-expressions).